# Error with dex2jar classes.dex file for reverse engineering of apk file

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, dex2jar

I am trying to extract the source code from an apk file and I am following the following steps
[Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

My problem is that when I execute the command dex2jar classes.dex I get a file not found exception.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the error in the command prompt I wasn't in the correct folder.